# maps package in R: Where is geometry data stored?

Tags: r, geometry, maps, polygon, r-sf

I did quite a lot of research and did not find an answer to the following questions regarding the [`maps`](https://github.com/adeckmyn/maps) package in R:

(EDIT: I did not notice that it only works with `ggplot2`, as I still had this package cached in RStudio and I had the wrong assumption that `map_data()` is part of `maps` package, [whereas it's part of `ggplot2`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.3.6/topics/map_data). It's inserted into the code now.)

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)

map_data('world')
```

This outputs the data from the data frame object. The columns are *long*, *lat*, *group*, *order*, *region*, and *subregion*. *long* and *lat* columns contain single values for longitude and latitude. No other geometry data is visible in the data frame.

```
map('world')
```

This plots a world map with country polygons.

So my questions are:

1. Where is the geometry data of the polygons being stored?
2. How can I access the geometry and work with it?
3. How can I transform the geometry data to other useful formats like an `sf` object for example?

I am quite new to R and maybe the answers are quite simple. Anyways, I could not find them by myself and any help is highly appreciated.

EDIT: My goal is to visualise polygons from the `'world'` data of the `maps` package on an interactive map using `leaflet`. But if this is too complicated, I can use other sources for country polygons as well.

Comment: Where have you looked?   That is, do you know how to examine  `foo$bar` or, for S4 objects,  `foo@bar` to see what data are inside the object returned from the function?  Further, take a look at other functions besides `map_data` to see what kinds of data are directly extractable.

Comment: In this case the answer is simple: data bases for `maps` package consist of points/lines/text. For details you can check https://github.com/adeckmyn/maps/tree/master/src. To play with `sf`-like objects I would suggest to use `geodata` package. Don't forget another fantastic source of data, available through `osmdata` :).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I have seen `foo$geometry` in other examples, but not regarding `maps` package. I use RStudio and check contents of variables either using the "Environment" tab or by direct output in the console. I will have a look at other functions from the package.

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko: OK, I checked your link to the respective parts of Alex Deckmyn's GitHub repository for the package. So far I did not see how it can help answer my question, unfortunately. Please see my newest edit at the bottom of my question. But thanks for mentioning the alternative libraries.

Comment: You've not told us where the `map_data` function comes from. Please add this information.

Comment: @Spacedman: Thanks for the hint. I actually thought that map_data() is part of the maps package, just like map(). Am I wrong?

Comment: If I run R and do `library(maps)` I don't get it. So you must be adding some other package to get it. Which packages are you using?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I must have had some libraries cached in RStudio when I checked the code to be inserted here. See my newest edit at the top of the question. It's actually coming from `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the `world` to `sf` like:

```r
map_obj <- maps::map("world", exact = FALSE, plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
map_obj |>
  sf::st_as_sf()

#> Simple feature collection with 253 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -180 ymin: -85.19218 xmax: 190.2708 ymax: 83.59961
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> First 10 features:
#>                      ID                           geom
#> 1                 Aruba MULTIPOLYGON (((-69.89912 1...
#> 2           Afghanistan MULTIPOLYGON (((74.89131 37...
#> 3                Angola MULTIPOLYGON (((23.9665 -10...
#> 4              Anguilla MULTIPOLYGON (((-63.00122 1...
#> 5               Albania MULTIPOLYGON (((20.06396 42...
#> 6               Finland MULTIPOLYGON (((20.61133 60...
#> 7               Andorra MULTIPOLYGON (((1.706055 42...
#> 8  United Arab Emirates MULTIPOLYGON (((53.92783 24...
#> 9             Argentina MULTIPOLYGON (((-64.54916 -...
#> 10              Armenia MULTIPOLYGON (((45.55235 40...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Regards,
Grzegorz

Comment: Thank you! That works. I will post my working solution based on your hints in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my full working solution including `leaflet` (simplified version of a project I'm currently working on). `map()` instead of `map_data()` as input for `sf::st_as_sf()` did the trick, with some additional parameters proposed in [Grzegorz Sapijaszko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74146159/20137557).

```
library(maps)
library(leaflet)

map_obj <- map("world", exact = FALSE, plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE) |>
  sf::st_as_sf()

leaflet() |>
  addTiles() |>
  addPolygons(data = map_obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I may be allowed to reformat your question so that you are after a world dataset (any world dataset) for use with leaflet maps in R - I would suggest a slightly different approach.

The `{maps}` package has lived a long and fruitful life, but it is by now not the most cutting edge technology. It stores the map internally, which places a hard limit on stuff like resolution (which relates to package size & CRAN limits) and frequency of updates.

I would say that the current trend is more towards using data via external providers, be it OpensStreetMap via excellent `{osmdata}` package or one of the more regionally inclined packages - there is `{tigris}` for the US, `{rgugik}` for Poland, `{mapSpain}` for Spain and a bunch of others - have a look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html#specific-geospatial-data-sources-of-interest if you wish.

My favorite instance of the world dataset lives in `{giscoR}`. It is ultimately based on data from [GISCO](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco), which is affiliated with Eurostat  of the EU. It is newer and for many use cases superior to the dataset that lives in `{maps}`. Among other things:

- it is known to have formally valid geometry (which can be a tricky issue in  spatial operations)
- you can specify resolution (and thus size) of your object
- you can specify year valid for boundary changes (2020 is the latest)

For an example in action consider this piece of code (note that unlike for `{maps}` based workflow a working internet connection is required; this should not be a problem as leaflet.js requires internet connection as well).

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)


world_dataset <- giscoR::gisco_get_countries(year = "2020",
                                             resolution = "20")

leaflet(world_dataset) %>% 
  addProviderTiles("Stamen.Watercolor") %>%  # just showing off a cheeky basemap... 
  addPolygons(label = ~CNTR_NAME)
```

[image: world map with cursor on Russia]

Comment: Thank you! This is absolutely helpful and I will refer to your solution for future use cases.